# how to convert temperature array to rgb array for opencv

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

i have an array (320x240) of temperature values and I want it to convert to rgb values that I specified for example:

```
blueRGBValue = (0,0,128)
temperatureArray =(24.532, 24.213, 24.1234, ...)
for i in range(len(temperatureArray)):
   if (temperatureArray[i] > 25 and temperatureArray[i]<=30):
   imageArray.append(blueRGBValue)
...
```

like this for all temperatureArray but i cannot assign rgb codes as tuples to imageArray. How can i do that?
I imageArray should be initiate as numpy.zeros first to be ndarray

Thanks for advices.

Comment: I presume your array is 320x240 and contains a floating point value at each location. Please save that with `np.savetxt()`. I presume you have something that maps temperatures to colours. Please clarify that completely. Then please share all that information - you'll probably need to use Dropbox or Google Drive. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store that rgb tuple into your np array you have to initialise your imageArray as follows:

`imageArray = np.zeros((size), dtype=(float,3))`

Note the dtype, you are storing 3 numbers of type float into your tuple.
Then you can add your rgb values with `imageArray[0] = rgb`